# What happens if SIGSEV/SIGILL or any other signal is generated from within signal handler code in linux?

Tags: c, linux, signals

For example in the following snippet -

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct sigaction old_sa;


void handle_sigsegv(int signo, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *ucontext)
{
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Caught Signal SIGSEGV\n", strlen("Caught Signal SIGSEGV\n")); 
    
    *(int*)1 = 0; //###2 // SIGSEGV is generated again here

    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "After crashing statement in signal handler\n", strlen("After crashing statement in signal handler\n")); 
    signal(signo, SIG_DFL);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Before kill\n", strlen("Before kill\n")); 
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    kill(pid, signo);
}

int main (void)
{
    printf("PID is  %d\n", getpid());
    struct sigaction  sa;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handle_sigsegv;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);

    *(int*)0 = 0;  //###1 // This will raise SIGSEGV
    return 0;
}
```

Output generated is -

```
PID is  279223
Caught Signal SIGSEGV
[1]    279223 segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

In the above code snippet, SIGSEGV will be generated again on line ###2 which is inside a signal handler. The program is exiting after this line.

Ideally, Line ###2 should also generate SIGSEGV and the correspnding signal handler should get called but I want to know why the program is exiting and not going into infinite loop of calling handle_sigsegv repeatedly from line ###2?

Comment: You have one shot to deal with the SEGV signal. If you blow it, you're toast.

Comment: Any doc to back your statement that it can be called only once?

Comment: It can be called multiple times, but if you SEGV inside your SEGV handler, the operating system thinks you're too inept to proceed and terminates your program.

Comment: I am trying to come up with logic so that the signal handler does not go into an infinite loop in any case.

Comment: I believe this is the intent of not allowing the handler to be re-entrant, it avoids that very situation.